# React Native how to make human body outline figure

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, animation, react-native-animatable

I will working on a body editing app.I Want to create a human body just like in the below image:

[image]

This figure will make on the user input like the user will input his height,weight,waist,arms,thighs and according to that measurement the  figure fill be resize.How can i be done.Right now i have no idea how to to start with this.

Comment: create and then modify an svg would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

install this React Native Library

> npm install react-native-body-highlighter --save

and see my code in Expo snack
https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/body-figure